# Hard Mode Secret Code Puzzle

Tags: cipher

So the other day I recieved a strange email (Antivirus cleared it as being safe) but all it contained was this image. Can anyone tell me what it says?

[image: Log=Decrypt\"Message sent without delay. Target:-Patriot- Inbound"]

Comment: It could be something similar to the [pigpen cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigpen_cipher).

Comment: Check ASCII codes.

Comment: Can it be assumed that the puzzle is solveable from a printed version of the image above alone? (Asking, because if you have *received this per email* it could theoretically be encoded in the digital file as well. )

Comment: @flawr maybe it's more like an obfuscated morse code ?

Comment: @Xoff I thought about that before, but then how do you interpret the circle with the dot in it? Is the circle considered one dash? Then how is it different from the slash and dot?

Comment: @flawr There are 9 symbols that may be considered (but I don't know how) as two symbols among 3 (like 1.dot, 2.bar, 3.space). So maybe (and it's a big one) each figure contains a pair (like (dot, bar) or (bar,space)) and some obfuscating decoration (additional dots and bars) that makes the whole thing less obvious....

Comment: So, I received another email a while back, with the number 12 on it. then another that said 11. Just got one that said 10. What does that mean?

Comment: @TK_Jones: Instead of posting the hints as comments, please edit your question, ideally in spoiler tags. Buried in the comment section, the hints will probably go unnoticed. Editing the question also has the advantage of pushing your question to to top of the active questions queue.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer.

If you attribute an unique letter for each of the symbol following this pattern :

> - A = inverted alpha
> - B = circle
> - C = seven
> - D = slash
> - E = backslash
> - F = triangle
> - G = inverted seven
> - H = inverted gamma
> - I = percent (slash with 2 points)

You get this message :

> ABCCCDBDDBECDBIDBF
>   ADBEAGABD
>   ABAIDBIADADDBCDBI
>   GHDBGABDDBIIEABDGCHDBG

---

If you count the **dots** on each symbol you get :

> 311111111111112111
>   311131311
>   31321123131111112
>   1011131111221311110111

---

If you count the **lines** on each symbol you get :

> 312221111112111113
>   311132311
>   31311113131112111
>   2311231111111311223112

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it says:

> `Message sent without delay. Target:-Patriot- Inbound`

Because:

> The alt-text of the image is `Log=Decrypt\"Message sent without delay. Target:-Patriot- Inbound"`
>
>  Note that this assumes that the image itself is a red herring, which seems weird, but possible.